Error 1452, cannot add a row containing a foreign key
Why do I get this error?
INSERT INTO `data_logic`.`classez` (
    `CLASS_ID`, `SUBJECT`, `SUBJECT_NUM`, `SECTION_NUM`, `CAREER`, 
    `CLASS_DURATION`, `GRADE_CRIT`, `MEET_TIME`, `MEET_DAYS`, 
    `CLASS_BUILD`, `CLASS_ROOM`, `INSTR_LNAME`, `INSTR_FNAME`, 
    `ENROLL_REQ`, `FK_SOFT_ID`) 
VALUES (
    '1208', 'COSC', '440', '1', 'Undergraduate', 
    '2024-12-10', 'ABC Grading', '09:30:00', 'Tuesday, Thursday', 
    'CCIT', '279', 'Muhammad', 'Nooh', 
    'C or better in COSC241', '')


1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`data_logic`.`classez`, CONSTRAINT `FK_BOOK_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`FK_BOOK_ID`) REFERENCES `text_books` (`BOOK_ID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)


Try using NULL instead of '' for the soft_id value, assuming the column is nullable.

If the datatype is INT, '' will be converted to 0. So you'll get an error if there's no text_books.book_id = 0

Are you sure you should have this foreign key in the first place? Why should there be a 1-to-1 correspondence between class and software, can't you use multiple (or no) softwares in the class? You should use a many-to-many relationship table rather than a FK in the classez table.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.. You've already provided the error message as text, so the image is nothing but a waste of bandwidth for those reading the post. Posting the text message was the proper action, and you did that, but then you made a mistake and also posted an image.

@KenWhite Don't forget to escape backticks in text.

@Barmar: Oops! I did forget. Thanks for fixing them.

You do NOT set the value into FK_BOOK_ID column which causes the problem. Provide CREATE TABLE scripts for both classez and text_books tables.
